# How to embed video in HD in videojs-youtube?

Tags: video.js

I have successfully use videojs-youtube to embed youtube video on my page http://malescast.com/Eksis-dengan-HexoJS/instalasi-hexojs

As you can see there, the video is not HD. In Youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bujxtMQouZ4 I could watch the video in HD.

Currently my setup is like this:

```
<video
      id="malescast-video"
      poster="/img/poster/hexo-part-01.jpg"
      class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
      controls preload="auto" width="640" height="360"
      data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "aspectRatio":"16:10", "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bujxtMQouZ4"}], "Youtube": { "ytControls": 2 }}'
       style="margin:auto;">
</video>
```

You can see it on the page.

I even change this to this:

```
<video
      id="malescast-video"
      poster="/img/poster/hexo-part-01.jpg"
      class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
      controls preload="auto" width="1280" height="800"
      data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "aspectRatio":"16:10", "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bujxtMQouZ4"}], "Youtube": { "ytControls": 2 }}'
       style="margin:auto;">
</video>
```

But still doesn't work. How to fix this? Or, is it possible to show quality selector while using videojs controls? Thanks.

Comment: The videojs guys flagged this as out of scope for the tech plugin: https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube/issues/312

Answer (score 0):

Within the plugin script there is a piece that passes options to fetch from YouTube iframe API, check it out:

`var playerVars={controls:0,modestbranding:1,rel:0,showinfo:0,suggestedQuality:'default',setPlaybackQuality:'highres',loop:this.options_.loop?1:0};`